# Javascript POST to Django via AJAX not working at all have run out of ideas

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, post

Hi we are just trying to post a javascript string variable to a django view. It sounds so easy but it is three days since I started trying to do this! I have practically read every relevant question on stack overflow and I just do not know what I am doing wrong..

JAVASCRIPT ON TEMPLATE HTML PAGE

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<!--also have a jquery file imported further up in my code - 
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
should be where it is getting ajax from, right?-->

<script language="JavaScript">
  $(function() {
  $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
  $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
  });

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#makeconstruct').submit(function()

{
        //Serializes the sortable's item id's into an array of string
        var senderStrIndexArray = $('#sortable').sortable();

    var linkOrder = $(senderStrIndexArray).sortable('toArray');
    alert(linkOrder);


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ecosystem/ajaxmes/",
        // The key needs to match your method's input parameter (case-sensitive).
        data: JSON.stringify({ linkOrder:linkOrder }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        //do we need json??
        success: function(data){alert(data);},
        failure: function(errMsg) {
            alert(errMsg);
        }
    });             
});
});
</script>
```

HTML ON TEMPLATE

```
<form id="makeconstruct" action="/ecosystem/ajaxmes/" method="post">
<!--DO WE NEED A METHOD/ACTION HERE IF IT IS DEFINED IN THE JAVASCRIPT??-->
{% csrf_token %}<!--view defined as csrf exempt but kept just in case-->
<ul id="sortable">
and a jQuery sortable list of things goes here in the code, each with an id
</ul>
<button type="submit">Submit</button></form>
```

VIEWS.PY

```
from django.utils import simplejson #not sure this is necessary given the code
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
@csrf_exempt
def ajaxmes(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        message = "Yes, I am the king!!!"
    else:
        message = "No, I am going to cry!!"
    return HttpResponse(message)
```

URLS.PY

```
url(r'^ecosystem/ajaxmes', 'container.views.ajaxmes'),
#Think this is the only line I need to show here
```

The alert for the javascript linkOrder variable works, but then all we get is the "No, I am going to cry" response. We really are desperate now, thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning false from your Javascript `submit` function. That means that the Ajax is fired, but before it has a chance to do anything, the default action of the button happens and the form is submitted normally, which is why the is_ajax function returns false. If the JS returns false, the action will not be fired.

Comment: Hi, we tried adding return false to seemingly every position and to to just before the closing bracket i.e.: submit.(function(){ CODE; return false;}) and we get the alert(linkOrder) but the page then just goes to the same page we were on. We also deleted the method="POST" and action="/ecosystem/ajaxmes/" bits from the form HTML as this is not needed (presumably?)

Comment: @bioinformagician pass event to your `submit(function(event))..` and go as the first line of the callback function `event.preventDefault();` and report back.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, if I do what I think you are asking, the alert comes up and once you click ok nothing else happens, it does not change page or reload the current page either.

Comment: @bioinformagician but that's what you want, isn't it? The whole point of using Ajax is to avoid reloading the page, but you haven't written any JS to actually change the current page either.

Comment: Ok, thanks this was the thing that was wrong with the script! event.preventDefault() worked in combination with some tussling with csrf stuff, having to include csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}' in the data section of the $.ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

try changing this `url(r'^ecosystem/ajaxmes', 'container.views.ajaxmes')`, to this `url(r'^ecosystem/ajaxmes/', 'container.views.ajaxmes'),`

you are sending the request to "/ecosystem/ajaxmes/" but since in your urls.py you don't have the trailing slash, it is getting redirected.

Comment: hi, we did that, then it told us to add a slash to the action of the form in the HTML, which we did. Then it was back to square 1 as we just got the "No I am going to cry" page. It seems that the $.ajax bit is not being accessed ever as we can totally change it and nothing happens, rather the form itself seems to directly call the view \